# Fire event on HDMI connection

Tags: software-development, input-device, software-recommendation

I want to run a script when an HDMI cable is connected, how would I do this? I found a couple links about how to do it generally in Ubuntu but nothing was working.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/263248/set-hdmi-sound-output-automatically-on-connect-disconnect

Comment: Hi and welcome to rasperrypi.SE. I would love to know what you tried and how it failed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this isn't possible. You could display something on the screen, though.